# mod_rewrite works in subdirectory not in base directory

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)/?$ storefront.php?id_user=$1 [L]
```

When placed in a subdirectory ie: `http://example.com/subdirectory/` it works on redirecting a url from `http://example.com/subdirectory/user` to `http://example.com/subdirectory/storefront.php?id_user=user`.

When place in base directory ie: `http://example.com/` it fails to redirect the url `http://example.com/user` to `http://example.com/storefront.php?id_user=user`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i try to visit the url `http://example.com/user` and it redirects me to `http://example.com/`

Comment: furthermore ive tried simple rewrite rules such as rewriting fileone.html to storefront.php and it works when i type `http://example.com/fileone.html` in the base directory

Comment: the fileone.html is an example i tried to verify rewriteengine was working from base directory, sorry for confusion. only concerned with the rewrite rule described in original question.

Comment: the code in the question is the entire .htaccess file in the root directory

Comment: Yes but that rule is **not redirecting `http://example.com/user` to `http://example.com/`**.

Comment: so why am i getting that effect and not the effect i want? especially when the same rule works in a subdirectory?

Comment: You need to be answering that question as I don't have your host and code.

Comment: You do not have a page named user.php or user folder ?

Comment: how to i begin answering that question? i have access to everything on the host and the code above is the the entire .htaccess file.

Comment: there are no folders name user or user.php, regardless isnt that what `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is suppose to take care off?

Comment: Well if you have “access to everything”, then enable rewrite logging, and you will see what is going on …

Comment: the error provided in the log is `[Tue Dec 09 12:36:54 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] File does not exist: /var/www/example.com/public_html/css, referer: http://example.com/user`

Comment: i added my css files to base directory and now i get no errors in my apache error log even with highest level of logging.

Answer (score 0):

okay i am getting the effect i want by using this rewrite rule which if feel is a hack and not the way it really should be. then again..it works so going with it unless someone enlightens me on what is happening.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)/?$ http://example.com/subdirectory/storefront.php?=id_user=$1 [L]
```

basically i rewrote it to the directory that was working. but ultimately this is not what i want since i want to migrate subdirectory to be base directory down the road and this issue is preventing that.